# AnchorPane растёт при добавлении новых элементов

Tags: java, javafx

У меня есть `AnchorPane`. В него добавляются линии, конечная точка которых - ширина этой панели. При добавлении линии, ширина панели увеличивается, хотя и установлено ограничение через `setMaxWidth()`. С обычной `Pane` этого не происходит (если ограничить максимальную ширину).

```
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    AnchorPane root = new AnchorPane(), pane = new AnchorPane();
    pane.setPrefSize(100,100);
    pane.setMaxWidth(100);
    root.getChildren().add(pane);
    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root,400,300));
    primaryStage.show();
    root.requestFocus();
    ObservableList children = pane.getChildren();
    root.addEventHandler(KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED, keyEvent -> {
        children.add(new Line(0,1,pane.getWidth(),1));
        System.out.println(pane.getWidth());
    });
}
```

Вот, что выводится в консоль (`pane.getWidth()`):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Попробуйте `AnchorPane` поместить в `ScrollPane` (или как-то там)

Comment: Мне это не подходит. Надо без скроллпейна.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Решил проблему. Надо помимо максимальной ширины ограничить ещё и минимальную. Не знаю, как это работает, но работает. Причём минимальную длину можно ставить какую угодно, главное, чтобы она была.